# Tour Virtual 360 - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Já fiz algumas integrações de mapas com a API do Google Maps para *JavaScript* em alguns clientes, verifiquei que os tipos de mapas conforme a [documentação de mapas básicos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes) são esses abaixo:

- `roadmap`- Exibe o mapa de vias padrão. Esse é o tipo de mapa padrão.
- `satellite` - Exibe imagens de satélite do Google Earth.
- `hybrid`  - Exibe uma combinação de visualizações normais e de satélite.
- `terrain` - Exibe um mapa físico baseado em informações do terreno.

[Neste site](http://www.tourvirtual360.com.br/tourvirtual/google-business-view) encontrei várias empresas que já tem suas imagens 360º no Google Maps, alguém poderia me dar um exemplo do código JavaScript para fazer a integração desse Tour 360º de uma empresa numa página Web?

Obrigado.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333995/google-maps-interior-do-estabelecimento/334003#334003

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que a documentação tenha aumentado sobre o Google Maps Street View. Agora existem exemplos concretos na documentação.

[Aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) você pode verificar a página principal sobre esse tópico na documentação, e [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) um exemplo concreto.