# Google Maps Interior do estabelecimento

Tags: google, maps

Bom dia, alguem pode me dizer como faço pra por o mapa do google de um determinado estabelecimento no site, no entanto quero que este exiba o interior dele, que consigo acessar no maps, mas quero por uma div com isso na minha page de contato, como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1538576086683!6m8!1m7!1sCAoSLEFGMVFpcE5qWUJPYlNYT0tDd3dRdG9tQkZ5RjB2RndraEtWNGlFZ290OG1u!2m2!1d-23.22514468500055!2d-45.92147622643756!3f256.199!4f0!5f0.7820865974627469" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Primeiro você tem que verificar se tem alguma imagem do local em 360º. Caso tenha:

1 - Vá ao Google Maps e selecione o local:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Clica em qualquer uma das imagens, e selecione Compartilhar ou incorporar imagem no menu superior esquerdo, do lado direito das imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Clica em Incorporar um mapa e copie e cole o código HTML:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: me ajudou demais,obrigado.

Comment: @ArthurAyrton, acredito que o problema foi resolvido.. marque a resposta como [**aceita**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)